# Model definition of array data in python flask-restplus swagger

Tags: rest, api, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I am using flask_restplus swagger in flask for api documentation. I want to create a model definition for an api that post data to the database. My problem is that, data is in array form. I am sending data in following format with post request.

```
{
    "user_id" : 3,
    "product" : [
        {
            "product_id" : 33,
            "total_price" : 50,
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "product_id" : 18,
            "total_price" : 40,
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

How we can define model for this type of structure? I am sending data in body.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: order = api.model('Order', {
 "user_id" : fields.Integer,
 "product" : {
   "product_id" : fields.String,
   "total_price" : fields.Integer,
   "quantity": fields.Integer
  }
})

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer, follow the following link for help
https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/18

I had the similar issue i used this link to solve my problem

Part of solution may be this help

```
{"product" : [
        {
            "product_id" : 33,
            "total_price" : 50,
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "product_id" : 18,
            "total_price" : 40,
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ]
}

order = api.model( "product" : { "product_id" : fields.String, "total_price" : fields.Integer, "quantity": fields.Integer } }) 



@api.route('/somewhere')
class MyAPI(Resource):
    @api.expect([order])
    def post(self):
        pass
or 

@api.route('/somewhere')
class MyAPI(Resource):
    @api.doc(body=[order])
    def post(self):
        pass
```

for "user_id" i will use 
`@api.extend` to extend my model and try, since i have not tried this so i cannot comment, you need to check this part and update